# Intersection of two numpy arrays while seeing the nested list as element

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have two arrays

```
A= [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]
B=[[2,1],[2,0],[3,0]]
```

n`p.intersect1d(A,B)` gives me `0,1,2,3`, but what I actually want is `[2,0]` and `[3,0]`. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
set([tuple(row) for row in A]).intersection([tuple(row) for row in B])

{(3, 0), (2, 0)}
```

You can then get this as an `np.array` like this:

```
tups = set([tuple(row) for row in A]).intersection([tuple(row) for row in B])

result = np.array([tup for tup in tups])

>>> result
array([[3, 0],
       [2, 0]])
```